# TypeError User.findOne is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Using this according to the documentation as well as online tutorials, is there something wrong with the way I am calling the Users model?

users.js

```
//User model
const User  = require('../models/User');

//Validation passed
        User.findOne({ email: email})
        .then(user => {
            if(user) {
                //user exists throw errors
            } else {
                res.send('create new user entry')
            }
        });
```

my User.js model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    });
    return User;
}
```

Comment: Your `User.js` exports a function not model, also looks like it requires 2 parameters

Comment: can you please share index.js file in models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your user model file from this

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {

    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    });
    return User;
}
```

to something like this

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../util/connection");
const User = sequelize.define("user", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  fname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});


module.exports = User;
```

the issue is with you user model file you are not correctly importing the user model.
or else try something like this.

```
//User model
const Usermodel  = require('../models/User');
const User = Usermodel(sequelize,Sequelize);

//Validation passed
        User.findOne({ email: email})
        .then(user => {
            if(user) {
                //user exists throw errors
            } else {
                res.send('create new user entry')
            }
        });
```

can you post your index.js file